# Why are my plots coming 1 below the other inspite of using the plotting function?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]I want to plot 2 figures side by side but for some reason they are coming 1 below the other. I've written the plotting code inside a function.

```
def team_comp(x,y,d,e):
a=[x,y]
mat_new1 = mat[mat['team1'].isin(a) & mat['team2'].isin(a)][['id', 'season', 'city', 'date', 'team1', 'team2', 'toss_winner',
   'toss_decision', 'result', 'dl_applied', 'winner', 'win_by_runs',
   'win_by_wickets', 'player_of_match']]
b=[d,e]
mat_new2 = mat[mat['team1'].isin(b) & mat['team2'].isin(b)][['id', 'season', 'city', 'date', 'team1', 'team2', 'toss_winner',
   'toss_decision', 'result', 'dl_applied', 'winner', 'win_by_runs',
   'win_by_wickets', 'player_of_match']]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
sns.countplot(x='winner', data=mat_new1)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,20,1))

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
sns.countplot(x='winner', data=mat_new2)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,20,1))
```

I later called the function like this

```
team_comp('DCAP','RR','MI','CSK')
```

Comment: The matplotlib documentation is full of examples of SUBPLOTS. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots please, check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "c", "a"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B": ["a", "b", "b", "b"]})

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,6))
sns.countplot(x = 'A' , data = df , ax = ax1 )
sns.countplot(x = 'B' , data = df2 , ax = ax2)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: output plots]